# Using the same code behind file to control page load on multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm developing a website using Dreamweaver CC as my html page editor and ASP.NET (VB) for the logic of how the website should work. I'm trying to initialize my session variables and assign them to some of the input fields in the page load event but it's not working. I only have one code behind file that it's a Partial Class named Services. In this file all I have are WebMethods that are called using ajax and javascript from the html pages. How can I control page load events for each of these html pages?

HTML Pages: AgentInfo.html, InsuredInfo.html, etc.

`Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        HttpContext.Current.Session("option1") = 0
        HttpContext.Current.Session("option2") = 0
        HttpContext.Current.Session("option3") = 0
        HttpContext.Current.Session("option4") = 0
    End Sub
End Class`

Comment: to run Page_Load events you need aspx pages, not html

Comment: Thanks for your answer Igor, is there another way to accomplish this? I want to initialize the session variables in the home page (Menu.html) and then I need to capture values and make them persist until the last page.  At the end, all of these session variables will be inserted to tables, but I already have a working web method for the insert. I'm a bit lost with the session variables and their states. Can you enlighten me to the approach I should take?